# htaccess: How to prevent recursive redirects?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, security

Here's the setup:

Wordpress and a webmail client are installed in the same directory. The webmail client is accessible through two URLs:

- `www.server.com/webmail`

  (The directory in which it is installed.)
- `www.server.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=webmail-plugin`

  (A wordpress plugin that **displays the webmail client in an iframe** inside wordpress admin.)

Now I'd like to have the webmail client accessiable only through the url `www.server.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=webmail-plugin` and block any direct access (from a user) to `www.server.com/webmail`.

In other words: If a user tries to access the webmail client through `www.server.com/webmail` it should be redirected to `www.server.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=webmail-plugin` (which forces the user to log in first). However, the wordpress plugin must still have to access `www.server.com/webmail` to be able to display the webmail client inside an iframe.

Can this be configured through .htaccess? If so, how?

A little background information:
I'd like to do this for security reasons: Wordpress is secured by various means, but the webmail client only supports basic authentication and the easiest way to prevent any issues with the webmail client is to hide it behind wordpress - i.e. having non of its interface (especially not the login page) exposed from outside wordpress.

**Edit: Why a simple redirect from `/webmail` to `/wp-admin` doesn't work:**

The difficulty is that wordpress and the webmail client are running on the same host. And when wordpress displays the webmail client it also loads it from `www.server.com/webmail`. Therefore, simply redirecting `www.server.com/webmail` to `www.server.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=webmail-plugin` would cause a recursion:

1. When the webmail interface should be displayed inside the **iframe**, wordpress tries to load `www.server.com/webmail`.
2. But the request gets redirected back to `www.server.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=webmail-plugin`, **causing the whole wordpress backend to be displayed (nested) inside the iframe**.
3. The **nested** wordpress backend again tries to display the webmail client (1.), which again gets redirected to the wordpress backend, and so on....

Can the recursion issue be fixed through .htaccess? If not, what other options do you suggest?

Your advise is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mail.server.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://server.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=webmail-plugin [L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise. Simply redirecting from the webmail folder to wordpress would cause a recursion. I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use Javascript on your web client to check if it is being called from inside an iframe. If it is not being called from an iframe, then the user can be redirected to the wordpress login page.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. It's a nice idea. However, the webmail client should not be exposed from outside wordpress, so I'm afraid but this is the wrong solution. I've updated the question accordingly.